# it is possible to backup sql server database in runtime

Tags: sql-server, backup

Can I use the "backup" transact sql command (sql-server 2008)

when my database is used (read/write) by other users.

Or I must switch to single_user mode before doing this?

Comment: Yes you can do backup online

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will let you do that.   There are considerations though, regarding full and precise restoration of the data should a restore operation become necessary.

Best you read up on the whole thing so you can choose the best back-up method for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the "backup" T-SQL command even the database is used (read/write) by other users. 
For example, you are going to make a full database backup by T-SQL command:

`BACKUP DATABASE Test TO DISK ='D:/Test.bak'`

Suppose someone is working with the table at this moment. So, the transaction "A" started before the full backup began, made some changes after the checkpoint and committed before the backup completed.

In this case, the full backup includes all transaction log records starting from the latest active transaction. This implies that the full backup includes the whole transaction "A" with all changes that were made after the checkpoint to apply those changes during the database recovery process.